# Reviewing unoptimized code in public repo. Are these type of question appropriate?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, on-topic

Currently I have a problem from a system that is not working properly [(ref in Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19403652/2029629).  It surely has many issues that might be related to both code optimization (PHP) as well as DB optimization.

I have made most of the code public at GitHub.  I will not ask for volunteers to review all my public code (if you volunteer I will appreciate the help).  But I would like to ask if the following types of questions are appropriate to either CodeReview.SE, another Stack Exchange site or a forum (but focused on CR.SE).

1. To draw attention on a specific issue and function and provide an URL to the public code in GitHub
2. To draw attention on a specific issue and function and copy it into the question.
3. SQL queries (which are some kind of code)
4. Code review of a whole module (and provide URL to the file in the public repo in GitHub)
5. Code review of larger parts of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Code Review meta, I can only answer for Code Review. Whether or not there exists other alternatives where these questions are on topic, I do not know.

> To draw attention on a specific issue and function and provide an URL to the public code in GitHub

No. The question on Code Review must include the code you want reviewed in the question itself. We don't want to depend on third party sources.

> To draw attention on a specific issue and function and copy it into the question.

If the is functional and *does what it is supposed to do*, and it is code *written by you*, then yes.

> SQL queries (which are some kind of code)

Yes, we have had several [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) questions already.

> Code review of a whole module (and provide URL to the file in the public repo in GitHub)

No. As said before, the code you want to have reviewed must be within the question itself.

> Code review of larger parts of the project.

If you include those parts in a question and the project is written by you, then yes. **However:**

- For questions containing a lot of code, **describe what your code is doing** and preferably also the **overall structure of your code**. Otherwise reviewers will have a hard time understanding what your code is supposed to do, which tends to cause your question to go unanswered.
- To make it easier for reviewers, consider splitting "large parts" into several "smaller parts".